# Javascript add element to form function not working?

Tags: php, javascript, html

Bear with me—this might be a bit confusing!

I have a javascript that adds (or removes) a new textarea + hidden field (to denote incrementation) to a form when a button is pushed. Here's the code:

```
function addRowToTable()
{ 

  var tbl = document.getElementById('convention');
  var lastRow = tbl.rows.length;
  // if there's no header row in the table, then iteration = lastRow + 1
  var iteration = lastRow;
  var row = tbl.insertRow(lastRow);



  // right cell
  var cellRight = row.insertCell(0);

  var el = document.createElement('textarea');
  el.rows = '2';
  el.cols = '80';
  el.name = 'conventionSkill' + iteration;
  el.size = 40;

    var el2 = document.createElement('input');
      el2.value = iteration;
  el2.type = 'hidden';
  el2.name = 'conventioni';



  el.onkeypress = keyPressTest;
  cellRight.appendChild(el);
    cellRight.appendChild(el2);


}

function removeRowFromTable()
{
  var tbl = document.getElementById('convention');
  var lastRow = tbl.rows.length;
  if (lastRow > 2) tbl.deleteRow(lastRow - 1);
}
```

This is appended to a form which is being presented through the following code:

```
//Convention




 echo "<form action='index.php?viewrubric=".$_GET['viewrubric']."&class=".$_GET['class']."' method='POST'>";
echo "<input type='hidden' name='rubricid' value='".$id."' />";
$sql2 = "select * from rubrics_convention where rubricid = '$id'";
$result2 = mysql_query($sql2) or die (mysql_error());

?>
<h3>Habit of Convention</h3>
<table>
<tr><td>
<label>Habit Description: </td></tr></label></table><textarea name='conventionDescription' rows='2' cols='80'><? echo $description; ?></textarea><br />

<table id="convention">
<tr><td><label>Skill Descriptions: </label>
</td></tr>

<?
while($row2=mysql_fetch_array($result2)) {
$convention_i++;
echo "<tr><td><textarea ".$readonly." name='convention_".$row2['id']."' rows='2' cols='80'>".$row2['skill']."</textarea></td></tr>";
}
echo "<input type='hidden' value=".$convention_i." name='conventioni' />";


echo "</table>";
echo '<input type="button" value="Add" onClick="addRowToTable();" />
<input type="button" value="Remove" onClick="removeRowFromTable();" />
';
```

Essentially, this is checking the database (rubrics_convention) for what has already been submitted. It populates the textareas with what's there. Now, I want it to be possible for a user to click the Add button and add a new textarea. The script right now does this, but when I submit, it doesn't even recognize convention_i's new value, or the new skill.

Processing the form:

```
if(isset($_POST['update'])) {
//Convention

echo $_POST['conventioni'];
}
```

Outputting 3, not 4, even after adding new form elements through javascript.

When I did "view selection source" in Firefox after clicking the "Add" button, here's the output:

```
  <input value="3" name="conventioni" type="hidden" />

  <table id="convention">
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td><label>Skill Descriptions:</label></td>
      </tr>

      <tr>
        <td>
        <textarea name="convention_1" rows="2" cols="80">
habit 1
</textarea></td>
      </tr>

      <tr>
        <td>
        <textarea name="convention_2" rows="2" cols="80">
habit 2
</textarea></td>
      </tr>

      <tr>
        <td>
        <textarea name="convention_3" rows="2" cols="80">
testest
</textarea></td>
      </tr>

      <tr>
        <td>
        <textarea name="conventionSkill4" cols="80" rows="2">
</textarea><input name="conventioni" value="4" type="hidden" /></td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>


    <input value="Add" onclick="addRowToTable();" type="button" /> <input value="Remove"
    onclick="removeRowFromTable();" type="button" />
```

Based on this output, you can clearly see that it's seeing the new conventioni value (the initial was 3, the javascript inserted a new one with a value of 4).  However, when submitting the form, it completely ignores that new value and looks at the 3 instead.  It doesn't even recognize conventionSkill4 as being there.

Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: You didn't post the php code that processes the form so we can't help you. But if I had to take a guess, it's not looking for conventionSkill4 because you didn't add code to look for it.

Comment: The only code i'm testing for processing the form is if the update button is pushed (which is towards the end of the form), and I'm having it echo $_POST['conventioni'].  Doing so echos 3, not 4, which is the problem I am facing.  I have updated my original post.

Comment: okay well you still need to post the code you are using for us to see where you are going wrong. I mean I can *assume* that by "conventioni" you really mean "convention".$i and $i is a counter and then I can *assume* that $i is a counter variable being used in a for(..) loop and you only have it counting to 3 instead of 4, but that's just making assumptions because you didn't post that code.

Comment: Basically everything is there. conventioni is a hidden input field with a value defined by the javascript based on the iteration. You can see in the html output that conventioni is 4, which it should be. However, when submitting the form, conventioni is being read as 3, which is the first variable defined (before the add button was pushed). It's as if the button was never pushed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks to me as if you're creating a *new* "conventioni" `<input>` each time you add a row, rather than simply updating the value of the input that's already there.  The result will be that your server will get multiple parameters called "conventioni".

Comment: Thanks for the response. I changed the javascript to add a new hidden input field called conventioni_alt.  Here's the output: <input name="conventioni_alt" value="4" type="hidden">

However, it's still not recognizing that submission when trying to echo $_POST['conventioni_alt'] after submitting the form.

Comment: Well you should use something like the [TamperData](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-us/firefox/addon/tamper-data/) Firefox plugin to inspect exactly what the outgoing HTTP requests look like. If the parameter is correctly set there, then you know that your problem is on the server.

Comment: I just tried using TamperData and it doesn't even seem to see the added javascript input fields. What could this mean?

Comment: Well it could mean that they're not getting added to the DOM properly. After the rows are added, you should be able to use a debugger to check what the DOM looks like and check whether the inputs are really there, and really **inside** the `<form>` block.

Comment: I'm not really sure what that means, but I use this script on another form, and TamperData picks it up perfectly. Can you perhaps guide me on how to check what's wrong? I used firebug and it's reading the HTML fine when adding new elements

Comment: <tr><td><textarea name="convention_1" rows="2" cols="80">habit 1</textarea></td></tr><tr><td><textarea name="convention_2" rows="2" cols="80">habit 2</textarea></td></tr><tr><td><textarea name="convention_3" rows="2" cols="80">testest</textarea></td></tr><input value="3" name="conventioni" type="hidden"><tr><td><textarea name="conventionSkill4" cols="80" rows="2"></textarea><input name="conventioni_alt" value="4" type="hidden"></td></tr></tbody></table><input value="Add" onclick="addRowToTable();" type="button">

Answer (score 0):

By looking at the final source, you have two inputs with the name 'conventioni'.

```
 <input value="3" name="conventioni" type="hidden" />
```

on line one

and

```
<input name="conventioni" value="4" type="hidden" />
```

Further down the script.

When referencing the 'conventioni' element it is most probably getting the value of the first element. Try either removing the first element, or simply just update it?

I cannot exactly say what code will be 100% correct but some to the effect of this may point you in the right direction:

```
element = document.getElementById('conventioni');
element.value = new_value;
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. I just responded to the other suggestion which basically said the same thing. Since I'm not quite sure what the update code would be, I just changed the javascript to add a field called conventioni_alt, however it's still not detecting it.